# How to stop python from converting int to float

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, int

I have an integer variable which casts into a floating point number as soon as i divide it. I need to stop this from happening

I've tried explicitly casting the variable after declaring it using the int() function but it still converted to a float as soon as i divided it

```py
x = 5
int(x)
x = x/2
type(x)
```

I expect the output of x/2 since its an integer but the output is 2.5, and when i run it through the type() function it returns a float

Comment: For integer division, use `x//2` (two slashes instead of one).  A single slash produces a floating result (this was a Python 3 change).

Answer (score 3):

There is no type-casting in Python, there is type conversion.

```
x = 5
int(x)
```

This has no impact on variable `x` as you've created a *new* (due to small integer ([-5, 256]) interning on CPython, it would be the same object to the original 5 in memory) `int` object by doing `int(x)` and throw it away because it has no name referring to it. The original `x` variable still referring to the integer object `5`.

When you divide `5 / 2` the answer is 2.5 which is a float, as shown in the result.

Now, if you want your result as `int`, you can do:

- **floor division**: `x // 2`  (`math.floor(x / 2)` would do as well)
- **use `round`**: `round(x / 2)`
- **ceil division**: `math.ceil(x / 2)` (this would get you 3 hence the name *ceiling*)